# How to create radio button in JBPM form modeler

Tags: jbpm, kie-workbench

I am using kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-jboss-as7.war and want to create a radio button in JBPM form modeler like below

```
Label----Employment Type
```

and I want radio button for below two fields

```
Self Employee
Salaried Employee
```

I saw Radio group option, but I do not understand how to use it.